# Keep a reference to an AsyncTask in an object that is being uploaded

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I successfully created a multiple photo uploader. It works as planned. Except I would like the ability to cancel the upload if I need to.

I know I can call `cancel()` on an AsyncTask if I need to cancel it.

What I would like to do is keep a reference to the AsyncTask in my photo upload object, so it can be referenced to cancel if necessary.

Doing the below works, but I can't get a reference to the async task.

```
UploadItem item = new UploadItem();
item.setItemFilePath(imageLocation);
item.setTaskIdentifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

new UploadTask().execute(item);
```

But I want to keep a reference to the task should I need to cancel it. So I did something like this but it crashes the app.

```
//Create new upload item
UploadItem item = new UploadItem();
item.setItemFilePath(imageLocation);
item.setTaskIdentifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
item.setAsyncTask(new UploadTask());

//Start the upload
item.getAsyncTask().execute(this);
```

***How do you keep a reference to an Async Task in a custom object?***

---

**My custom upload object.**

```
public class UploadItem implements Serializable {


    public AsyncTask mAsyncTask;
    public String itemFilePath = "";
    public String taskIdentifier = "";
    public boolean isUploading = false;


    public AsyncTask getAsyncTask() {
        Log.d("Upload Item", "Getting upload task");
        return mAsyncTask;
    }

    public void setAsyncTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
        Log.d("Upload Item", "Setting upload task");
        this.mAsyncTask = asyncTask;
    }

    public String getItemFilePath() {
        return itemFilePath;
    }

    public void setItemFilePath(String itemFilePath) {
        this.itemFilePath = itemFilePath;
    }


    public boolean isUploading() {
        return isUploading;
    }

    public void setUploading(boolean uploading) {
        isUploading = uploading;
    }


    public String getTaskIdentifier() {
        return taskIdentifier;
    }

    public void setTaskIdentifier(String taskIdentifier) {
        this.taskIdentifier = taskIdentifier;
    }
}
```

**The background task:**

```
  public class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<UploadItem, Integer, HashMap<String, String>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {  }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) { }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> r) { }

    }
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?